# VBA - if condition is fulfilled then put formula to another column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm struggling with macro, where I would like to have this:

I have table with columns A - AH and rows will be variable. If column A contains "Customer" then it should put the formula (=$K$1&V3) to the column L. In the other words, if on the 3rd row, column A3 is "Customer", then on L3 will put the formula. On 4th row, column A4 is not "Customer", but something else, then cell L4 should be untouched. I would like to use it for all cells, it means, that the macro should recognize, where is the end of the table = since the number of rows will change day from day.

I already have this code:

```
Sub testFind()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngFound As Range

Set rng = Range("A:A")

Set rngFound = rng.Find("Customer")

If rngFound = "Customer" Then
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R1C11&RC[10]"

Else


End If


End Sub
```

But it doesn't work, obviously :).

Many thanks for any advice!

Comment: Just curious why you'd need VBA? In `L1`, you could do `=If($A1="Customer",[formula],"")`, and drag down, no?

Comment: Oh yes, that would works also, but the files are changing for every day and I thought, that solution via VBA could be smoother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a VBA solution, you can use the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

```
Option Explicit

Sub testFind()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim rng As Range, C As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' <-- replace "Sheet1" with your sheet's name
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' last row in column A
    Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LastRow) ' set the dynamic range to be searched

    ' loop through all cells in column A
    For Each C In rng
        If C.Value = "Customer" Then
            C.Offset(, 11).Formula = "=$K$1&V" & C.Row ' use offset to put the formula on column "L"
        End If
    Next C
End With

End Sub
```

**Note**: if the value in column "A" consists of the word "Customer" (doesn't have to be exact match before and after), then use the line below:

```
If C.Value Like "*Customer*" Then
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - can be used to find last row in table
and use If to check if column A contains "customer"--

```
    If Activesheet.formulaRC[-10]= "customer" then
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]&RC[11]"
    end if
```

now loop through rows